# Raise validation error in email which accept yahoo, gmail and outlook only

Tags: django

I'm raising custom validation error in email field which accept only yahoo, gmail and outlook only. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile, Testimonial

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  username = forms.CharField()
  first_name = forms.CharField()
  last_name = forms.CharField()
  email = forms.EmailField()

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

  def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_exists = User.objects.filter(email=email) 
    accepted_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'outlook.com', 'hotmail.com'] 
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')  
    _, domain = email.split('@')
    if email_exists.exists():     
      raise forms.ValidationError("Email is taken") 
    elif domain.lower() not in accepted_domains:      
      raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
    return email
```

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
accepted_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'outlook.com']

_, domain = email.split('@')
if email_exists.exists() and not self.instance and self.instance.pk==None:
  raise forms.ValidationError("Email is taken") 
if domain.lower() not in accepted_domains:
  raise forms.ValidationError("Email should be gmail, yahoo and outlook only")
return email
```

Comment: Thank you it save my day, by the way what is _, use for.

Comment: split using `@` will return 2 results. I am catching it using `_, domain`. So, `_` will have `xyz` if I split `xyz@gmail.com`

Comment: How can I bypass the validation error **email is taken** when i updating user profile `if email_exists.exists():
  raise forms.ValidationError("Email is taken") `

Comment: Can you please ask a new question regarding this? :) its kind of out of context for the current one :) Also please share the question with me, I will be glad to help you out.

Comment: I just edit my question above, I cannot update first_name and last_name the email validation error "Email is taken" always appear